# Does ng-src also add src attribute to image tag?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I had an angular code for an image like `<img class="testClass" ng-src="{{ImagePath}}" alt="{{imageName}}" />`

However when after the page loads, I see an `src` attribute to the `img` tag as shown below.

`<img class="testClass" ng-src="/files/imageName_1.jpg" alt="Image 1" src="/files/imageName_1.jpg">`

So, does angular add `src` attribute as well by default?

Example jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wktwL/5/

If we inspect the element on the output image, we can see both ng-src and src attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, angular adds the appropriate HTML tag's attribute for all the valid ng-* directive.

Basically, you add the 'ng-src' for an element; When angular starts the parsing of the HTML and it encounters the 'ng-src' attribute it tries to find the registered 'ngSrc' directive when found it invokes that directive and that directive's logic adds the src tag.

From the AngularJS website:

> Using AngularJS markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until AngularJS replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.
>
> The buggy way to write it:
>
> `<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description"/>`
>
> The correct way to write it:
>
> `<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description" />`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AngularJS add the appropriate HTML tag attribute for valid ng-* directive.
AngularJs is always convert directive to html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way I see angular implementation and docs, angular adds the src attribute to img tag along with ng-src attribute